# List of Text and Grid of Images on the same screen android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm following the following tutorial  http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/combining-gridview-and-listview-in-one.html

I'm attempting to change the list view to use an array of strings, and display text rather than images for the bottom part of this application.

I'm not entirely sure what I should be using as my ListView ID here.  It seems like I can only use a findViewbyID, but I'd rather just give it an array of strings to populate that list view.  Am I missing something simple here?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_grid, CORPS);
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(????);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the code

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {

private ExpandableHeightGridView gridView;
private ListView listView;

//drawables array for listview
private static final int[] corpImage = { R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.blackberry_logo,
        R.drawable.google, R.drawable.microsoft, R.drawable.mozilla, R.drawable.oracle };

static final String[] CORPS = new String[] { "Microsoft", "Google", "Apple" };

//drawables array for gridview
private static final int[] osImage = { R.drawable.bbos, R.drawable.firefox_os,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ios, R.drawable.tizen, R.drawable.ubuntu_touch,
        R.drawable.wpos, R.drawable.symbian };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    addGridViewAsListViewHeader();

    setAdapters();
}

/**
 * set header for listview (it's a gridview)
 */
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
private void addGridViewAsListViewHeader() {
    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_gridview, null);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);

    gridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) header.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    // set expand to show all gridview rows
    gridView.setExpanded(true);
}


/**
 * set adapters for list view and gridview
 */
private void setAdapters() {
    // convert int array to Integer array by apache common lang library
    Integer[] osImageList = ArrayUtils.toObject(osImage);
    Integer[] corpImageList = ArrayUtils.toObject(corpImage);

    //Added by me but not working correctly
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_grid, CORPS);
    //ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.image);
   // lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // set listview and gridview adapters
    CustomAdapter gridViewAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.item_grid, R.id.image, osImageList);
    CustomAdapter listViewAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.item_grid, R.id.image, corpImageList);

    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to only use one string in each line, and display it as a list of items you can simply do this by using array adapters as follows.

```
ArrayList<String> companies = new ArrayList<>();
companies.add("Google");
companies.add("Microsoft");
// Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
ListView companiesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

// Create a new {@link ArrayAdapter} of earthquakes
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, earthquakes);

// Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
// so the list can be populated in the user interface
companiesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In your layout file you should declare a list view where you want to display this list of items. In this case id of that list view would be "list"